# Как массово пронумеровать файлы по порядку

Tags: bat

У меня есть 35000 файлов с расширением .png.pvr.ccz и хаотичным названием, их нужно переименовать в 1.png.pvr.czz 2.png.pvr.czz 3.png.pvr.czz и т.д.

Comment: В каком порядке? Произвольном?

Comment: И еще вопрос, в папке присутствуют файлы с другой маской?

Comment: Подобную задачу я решал парсером **FOR /F**, который обрабатывал листинг файлов в нужном мне порядке сортировки по дате модификации (можно и по имени).Листинг был организован командой **DIR**.